# Copying files while preserving directory structure

Tags: powershell, copy, restore

One of our sites was recently hit by a CryptoLocker infection.  Fortunately we caught it early and only have about 8k files encrypted out of the 200k or so on the file-system.  Our backups were good too, so I can restore the files

I have a list of all ~8k of the encrypted files in roughly the following format, one file per new line:

```
\\nas001\DATA\IQC\file.xls
\\nas001\DATA\IQC\file2.xls
\\nas001\DATA\IQC\folder1\file1.xls
\\nas001\DATA\IQC\folder3\file1.xls
```

I did an ndmp copy of a snapshot of good data, so the backup I am restoring form is another volume on the nas with the same folder structure after a certain point:

```
\\nas001\IQC_restore\file.xls
\\nas001\IQC_restore\file2.xls
\\nas001\IQC_restore\folder1\file1.xls
\\nas001\IQC_restore\folder3\file1.xls
```

Is there an easy way with powershell (or really, with batch scripting or robocopy) parse the files with the list of encrypted files and copy only those files from our backup to the original location, overwriting the encrypted files?  On another solution I found the following script:

```
$a = Get-Content "C:\script\hname.txt" 
foreach ($i in $a) 
    {$files= get-content "C:\script\src.txt"
    foreach ($file in $files)
    {Copy-Item $file -Destination \\$i\C$\temp -force}
    }
```

Which is almost what I need - the `foreach $i in $a` statement is redundant because I only have one $i, and it's copying all the files listed in the to a single folder rather than copying them in a way to preserve folder structures.

What's the best way to do this?  Can I pass it two separate files and tell it to link the two line for line, so for each line in file *a* it copies the file to the path in file *b*?  Is it easier to pass it one set of files (file *a*), perform a string replacement, and copy to that location?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am perhaps making too broad an assumption here - but really the paths between encrypted and restored files are identical as long as you make the appropriate substitution between `\\nas001\DATA\IQC` and `\\nas001\IQC_restore` correct? If so....

You can simply take each file from the "known bad files" file (`hname.txt`?) and substitute the correct path for the destination using the [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) method:

```
$files = Get-Content C:\script\hname.txt
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $src = $file.Replace("\\nas001\DATA\IQC","\\nas001\IQC_restore")
    Copy-Item $src -Destination $file -Force
}
```

Or, to be even more brief:

```
$enc = '\\nas001\DATA\IQC'      # encrypted files share/folder
$good = '\\nas001\IQC_restore'  # clean share/folder
gc c:\scripts\hname.txt | % { copy $_.replace($enc,$good) -dest $_ -force }
```

The secret decoder ring:

- **gc** is an alias for the [Get-Content](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx) cmdlet
- **%** is an alias for the [ForEach-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849731.aspx) cmdlet
- **$_** is a special variable inside a foreach scriptblock that represents the "current item" that is being passed in from the pipeline - in this case each line from the input file hname.txt

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for, and the explanation was very helpful as well.  Yes, the paths are identical as long as you perform the substitution.

Comment: You are very welcome. And thank you for joining the StackOverflow community! It is also worth mentioning that accepting answers is important (thank you!) and up-votes help identify good and helpful content as well - just click the up arrow above the green check mark for the accepted answer once you have earned 15 reputation points (you are very close!). More info: http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote