# Powershell copy a file from source to target but maintain folder structure

Tags: powershell, copy

How can I come up with a powershell script that can copy a file from a location A to location B and create new folder and maintain the sub directory structure

Pseudo code

```
$newFolder = "PackageName"
$maintainFolderStructureFrom ="Website"
$FileToCopy = "File.ascx"

Copy-Item "C:\A\B\Website\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3\"+$FileToCopy "C:\Client\Packages\$newFolder" -Container -Recurse
```

Now it should create the target as such

```
C:\Client\Packages\PackageName\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3\File.ascx
```

Code based on @jisaak answer

```
$newFolder = "NewFolderName"
$FileToCopy="File.ascx"                                                                                                
$pathToCopy = Join-Path 'C:\A\B\Website\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3\' $FileToCopy     
$destination = Join-Path 'C:\Client\Packages\' $newFolder                                                        
mkdir $destination -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue                                                                                      
Copy-Item $pathToCopy $destination
```

This code is not creating folder structure, I want the folder structure to be created user this param   $maintainFolderStructureFrom ="Website"

Comment: In PowerShell 5, the `Copy-Item` cmdlet has a `-Recurse` switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taking help of few answers from @jisaak & @FoxDeploy, I could accomplish what I need.

```
function CreatePackage($sourcePath, $fileSelectorToCopy, $packageName) {

$maintainStructionFrom = "Website"

$files = Get-ChildItem $sourcePath | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $fileSelectorToCopy}

$files | ForEach-Object { 
    $newFolder = $packageName
    $fileSelectorToCopy = $_.Name 
    $pathToCopy = Join-Path $sourcePath  $fileSelectorToCopy                                                                                         
    $newFolder = $newFolder+'\'+$pathToCopy.Substring($pathToCopy.IndexOf($maintainStructionFrom),$pathToCopy.Length - $pathToCopy.IndexOf($maintainStructionFrom)).Replace($fileSelectorToCopy,'') 
    $destination = Join-Path 'C:\Client\Packages\' $newFolder  
    mkdir $destination -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue                                                                                      
    Copy-Item $pathToCopy ($destination+$FileToCopy)
}
}
```

Then call it as

```
CreatePackage -packageName 'MyNewPackage' -fileSelectorToCopy 'FileNameLike.*' -sourcePath 'C:\A\B\Website\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3\'
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use the [Join-Path](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113347) cmdlet to combine paths. You could create the directories using `mkdir` (use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to ignore errors if the directory already exists):

```
$pathToCopy = Join-Path 'C:\A\B\Website\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3' $FileToCopy
$destination = Join-Path 'C:\Client\Packages' $newFolder

# create the directory if necessary
mkdir $destination -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 

Copy-Item $pathToCopy $destination
```

Comment: This code is not creating folder structure, I want the folder structure to be created user this param   $maintainFolderStructureFrom ="Website"

Comment: This creates the destination folder structure from $destination. What do you mean it not creating folder structure?

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas here:

- The `New-Item` cmdlet can create files and folders, including the necessary parent folder if they don't exist. Use the `-Force` switch. What's more, it will return a `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` type object for you to work with.
- If you make the `$pathToCopy` variable a `[System.IO.FileInfo]` object you get a few useful properties and methods in common with other files that you may be used to after using the `Get-Item` cmdlet.
- The `Resolve-Path` cmdlet can be useful to give a consistent format for your paths (e.g. '\' rather than '/', etc.) but note that it needs to resolve to something that actually exists. Remember to pull out the **Path** property of what that cmdlet gives you.
- There is a cool "Escape" method associated with the `[Regex]` class that can help stripping off parts of a file path.

The following shows off some of these things that you may or may not want to use:

```
$SourceRoot = "C:\A\B\Website"
$SourcePath = "\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\SubFolder3"
$SourceFile = "File.ascx"
$DestRoot = "C:\Client\Packages"
$NewFolder = "PackageName"

# Build a full path to your source file
$FileToCopy = Join-Path -Path $SourceRoot -ChildPath $SourcePath
$FileToCopy = Join-Path -Path $FileToCopy -ChildPath $SourceFile

# Make this a FileInfo object, just because we can :-)
$FileToCopy = $FileToCopy -as [System.IO.FileInfo]

# Or you could have used Get-ChildItem instead:
$FileToCopy = Resolve-Path ($SourceRoot+$SourcePath+$SourceFile)
$FileToCopy = Get-ChildItem -Path $FileToCopy.Path 

# Strip off the "root" folders so we're just left with the relative
# path to the source file from the source root folder
$RelativePath = $FileToCopy.Directory -replace [Regex]::Escape($SourceRoot),''

# Join up the destination path components
$DestFolder = Join-Path $DestRoot $NewFolder
$DestFolder = Join-Path $DestFolder $RelativePath

# Create the target folder if necessary & convert the $DestFolder
# variable into a [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] object!

$DestFolder = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $DestFolder -Force

# Copy the file
Copy-Item $FileToCopy $DestFolder
```

This is definitely a longer way to do this than you'll probably want to use, but I wanted the example to include a number of the ideas you could try.

Comment: Any time that I need to duplicate a folder structure, I use New-Item to first layout the directory structure, then copy items into their final place.  Why?  Well, Copy-Item, even when using the `-Force` switch, doesn't actually replicate folder structure like you'd think it would.  It's misleading and can result in Copy commands failing because the destination folder doesn't exist.

Comment: Yup, `New-Item` is useful like that. In this case (OP) you should be able to nail it in just one `New-Item` statement, as you only need to the structure between the root path and the specific file, and the cmdlet will fill in any missing intermediary folders in the path if necessary. Calling in ROBOCOPY to help may be even easier as that does behave as you describe, but sometimes it is nice to keep it in-house, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answers to similar questions:

- You could try using `RoboCopy`, as per an answer to a similar question here:

> [What's the proper way to copy files while preserving folder structure in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694961/whats-the-proper-way-to-copy-files-while-preserving-folder-structure-in-powersh?rq=1)

Or look at the answer here:

> [Copying files while preserving directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913855/copying-files-while-preserving-directory-structure?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I like some of the answers, but feel that they're overly verbose, so I'll offer a shorter take on the same thing.

The flow here is to recursively grab the source directory as `$source`.  Next, iterate through it, pulling out all the directories, and for each of those, make a new folder in the target.

Finally, go back through `$source` one last time to get the files this time, and put them in the new location.

```
$source = DIR -Path C:\SomeOldPath -Recurse
$destination = 'C:\SomeNewPath'
$source | Where PSIsContainer | ForEach-Object {
    #If the folder doesn't exist in the target
    if(!(Test-Path $Destination\$_.Name -PathType Container)){
        New-Item -Path $Destination\$_.Name -ItemType directory -Force}
        }
        else {
        Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $Destination\$_.Name -Force}

$source | Where PSIsContainer -eq $false | ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $Destination\$_.Name -Force
    }
```

Comment: ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'RemainingScripts'. Cannot convert the "Else" value of type "System.String" to type 
"System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
At line:4 char:33
+ $source | Where PSIsContainer | ForEach-Object {
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ForEach-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand