# Copy file and folder maintaining the structure

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I want to write a powershell script which copies the source files and folders to a destination. Please see the structure of source below.

```
C:\
  Web
      Index.html
      Web.config
      Bin
        web.dll
        lib.dll
        json.dll
      Content
            img
               pic.png
               profile.png
            theme 
               dark.png
            Style.css
```

I want to maintain the same structure in destination.

Suppose If I do

```
Copy-Item "C:\Web" -Destination "d:\Web" -recurse -force
```

I need to have same structure in both the places. And also If i execute multiple time the same command, The structure should be same. And the content should be overwritten in destination.

Comment: You're looking for [`robocopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy).

Comment: I want to do it in powershell. I can't use any external tool. Please let me  know.

Comment: The complete module is written in powershell. I need to replicate in this case source folders and files  exactly same at destination. And this replication can execute multiple times. If files or folders  exist it should overwrite

Comment: `robocopy` ships with Windows. You're asking how to re-invent the wheel. My advice to that is: don't.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers It is completely in powershell we did not use any external exe. All the things is written in purly in powershell modules. Is this not possible in powershell? If not i can definitely try to use robocopy. By the way how do I do in robocopy and how to integrate that with powershell?

Comment: Of course it's possible in PowerShell. It's just pointless effort.

Comment: Can i get an example of it. In powershell or in robocopy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell copy a file from source to target but maintain folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942581/powershell-copy-a-file-from-source-to-target-but-maintain-folder-structure)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Using PowerShell only might be important if the code ever runs on Linux or Mac.

Comment: In PowerShell 5, the `Copy-Item` cmdlet has a `-Recurse` switch.

Comment: @lit Or, one could simply add a switch to invoke either `rsync` or `robocopy` depending on the OS should running on Unix or Linux ever become relevant. Also, the `-Recurse` switch was already present in version 2. However, it'll throw an error for all files that already exist in the destination folder, so you'd need `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, which would also suppress other errors.